# MYSQL SUM field with join and condition

Tags: mysql

I have two table with different amount of rows, i want SUM field (jumlah) but the field which should be from 2nd table is empty instead filled with number from other field

> This My sql query

```
SELECT a.nama_kebutuhan, SUM(a.jumlah) as jumlah1, SUM(b.jumlah) as jumlah2
FROM kebutuhan AS a 
INNER JOIN supply AS b ON b.no = a.no
WHERE a.no = '17717072'
GROUP BY a.`nama_kebutuhan`
```

Table kebutuhan

```
id |   no   | nama_kebutuhan | jumlah
-------------------------------------
151|17717072| Pagar Panel MF | 10
152|17717072| U 30.30.120 T3 | 30
```

Tabel supply

```
id |   no   | nama_barang  | penyedia
-------------------------------------
1  |17717072|U 30.30.120 T3|  5
```

The result should be

```
 nama_kebutuhan | jumlah1 | jumlah2
-------------------------------------
 Pagar Panel MF |   10    |  NULL
 U 30.30.120 T3 |   30    |   5
```

Comment: use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. AND in condition ON b.no = a.no AND a.nama_kebutuhan = b.nama_barang.

Comment: @RahulBiswas i've tried it, but same like inner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN and ADD nama_kebutuhan = nama_barang with no in ON clause for retrieving desired output.

```
-- MySQL (v5.8)
SELECT k.nama_kebutuhan
     , SUM(k.jumlah) AS 'jumlah'
     , SUM(s.penyedia) AS 'jumlah2' 
FROM kebutuhan k
LEFT JOIN supply s 
       ON s.no=k.no 
      AND k.nama_kebutuhan = s.nama_barang
WHERE k.no = '17717072'       
GROUP BY k.nama_kebutuhan;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c30cd911a29a01c6b89b334d335e5ce

Comment: @kristianferdy3 please check this and let me know if any query regard this.

Comment: i was tried to change like that, but in another case if i add some data with difference no in table_2(suplly) it will be SUM all in table_2(supply), i thought if ON repalced with k.nama_kebutuhan = s.nama_barang the condition just only in table_1(kebutuhan) not both

Comment: Please provide few data related this and your expectation. I've submitted this one as per your question.

Comment: oh just need 2 ON in JOIN, it verry helping me

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT k.nama_kebutuhan, SUM(k.jumlah) AS 'jumlah', SUM(s.penyedia) AS 'jumlah2' FROM kebutuhan k
LEFT JOIN supply s ON s.no=k.no
GROUP BY k.nama_kebutuhan;
```

Comment: i've tried left, and right join, but the result same like inner join